# How to fix warning 'Invalid number of arguments, expected 0' for dispatch method of useReducer in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this warning while I don't use typescript in this project.

[image]

My code:

```
const initialState = {
    data: {name: '', password: '', code: ''},
    isChecked: false,
    error: {security: false},
    captchaNumber: Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000,
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'input':
            return {...state, data: {...state.data, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value}}
        case 'checkbox':
            return {...state, isChecked: action.payload}
        case 'error':
            return {...state, error: {...state.error, security: action.payload}}
        case 'captcha':
            return {...state, captchaNumber: action.payload}
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState, undefined)
    let passwordRef = useRef();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        dispatch({type: 'input', payload: {name: [name], value: e.target.value}})
    }
    const handleChecked = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'checkbox', payload: !state.isChecked})
        if(passwordRef.current.type === 'password'){
            passwordRef.current.type = 'text';
        }
        else {
            passwordRef.current.type = 'password';
        }
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(state.captchaNumber.toString() !== state.data.code){
            return dispatch({type: 'error', payload: true})
        }
        else if(state.error.security === true){
            dispatch({type: 'error', payload: false})
        }
        navigate('home')
    }
    const handleNewCaptcha = () => {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000
        dispatch({type: 'captcha', payload: random})
    }
    return(
.
.
.
)
```

It works fine, I just want to get rid of it.

Comment: Can you provide revelant code instead of image?

Comment: @LãNgọcHải, Ok, but I used image to help you see the warning in webstorm.

Comment: Where did you import `useReducer` from and what version of React are you using? Have you added the relevant `@types/react` to your `devDependencies`?

Comment: @Phil, I'm sorry, I deleted those imports cause I thought it's not neccessary. Component works well. React version: ^18.2.0. No I haven't. how to do that?

Comment: You just add them with `npm` / `yarn` / whatever. Eg `npm install -D @types/react @types/react-dom`